# How to start a TornadoFX app from a launcher class

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

It's [well known](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236#issuecomment-426583174) that for a fatjar to run properly for more recent versions of javafx applications the main class that launches the application cannot inherit from the Application class. The easy work around is creating a launcher class that calls the main method of the main class.

I'm having trouble doing this with Kotlin and TornadoFX (pretty new to both).

My example app is minimal:

```
class MyApp: App(MainView::class, Styles::class)
```

The question is how can I start this class from another launcher class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done is put the function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

In the same file, but outside of the App class. I then have my IDE and build tool (Maven in my case) point to this file.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest and possibly best way to do this is with a function as follows.

If we make a Kotlin file Launcher.kt name is not important. Contents below

```
package my.app

class MyApp: App(MainView::class, Styles::class) 

// stand alone function
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

then the main class name would be 
`mainClassName = 'my.app.MyAppKt'`

now we have a main class declaration this is used in the jars manifest or we could use the shaddow plugin for creating fat jars as shown here [Shadow JAR](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/application-plugin/)

Note the launch function here is from tornadofx.App.kt